# How to do hardware UART using Atmega8

Tags: uart, atmega, avr-gcc

I have recently come up to program Atmega8 with no external crystal for serial communication using hardware uart.
I have checked  many code samples and libraries.
But at the end there was no success:
This is the code:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#define UART_BAUD 19200

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BAUDRATE ((F_CPU)/(UART_BAUD*16UL)-1)            // set baud rate value for UBRR
  
// function to initialize UART
void uart_init (void)
{
    UBRRH = (BAUDRATE>>8);                      // shift the register right by 8 bits
    UBRRL = BAUDRATE;                           // set baud rate
    UCSRB|= (1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXEN);                // enable receiver and transmitter
    UCSRC|= (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<UCSZ1);   // 8bit data format
}

// function to send data
void uart_transmit(unsigned char data)
{
    while (!( UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));                // wait while register is free
    UDR = data;                                   // load data in the register
}

// function to receive data
unsigned char uart_recieve(void)
{
    while((!(UCSRA)) & (1<<RXC));                   // wait while data is being received
    return UDR;                                   // return 8-bit data
}

int main(void)

{
    DDRB = 0b00000001;              // set LED pin as OUTPUT 
    PORTB = 0b00000001;             // set all pins to LOW
    
    uart_init();
    while (1)
    {
        for(unsigned char i=10; i< 127; i++)
        {
            uart_transmit (i);
            _delay_ms(10);
        }
        uart_transmit ('A');
        uart_transmit (13);
        uart_transmit (10);
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB = 1-PORTB;
    }
     
    return 0;
}
```

The code is written to send date at baud rate of **19200** with **8** bit length, **N**o parity bits and **1** stop bits.

The problem is that when I check the out put using a USB to TTL converter and terminal program, I get the following results for the above code for a configuration of ***19200-7-N-2*** and ***19200-7-N-1***

```
0A 0B 0C 0D 0E - 0F 10 11 12 13    .....  .....
14 15 16 17 18 - 19 1A 1B 1C 1D    .....  .....
1E 1F 00 01 02 - 03 04 05 06 07    .....  .....
08 09 0A 0B 0C - 0D 0E 0F 10 11    .....  .....
12 13 14 15 16 - 17 18 19 1A 1B    .....  .....
1C 1D 1E 1F 20 - 21 22 23 24 25    ....   !"#$%
26 27 28 29 2A - 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F    &'()*  +,-./
30 31 32 33 34 - 35 36 37 38 39    01234  56789
3A 3B 3C 3D 3E - 3F 20 21 22 23    :;<=>  ? !"#
24 25 26 27 28 - 29 2A 2B 2C 2D    $%&'(  )*+,-
2E 2F 30 31 32 - 33 34 35 36 37    ./012  34567
38 39 3A 3B 3C - 3D 3E 21 0D 0A    89:;<  =>!..
```

At this configuration it seems to be a missing bit no. 6
For a configuration of **19200-8-N-2** and **19200-8-N-1** I get the following results in terminal

```
8A 8B 8C 8D 8E - 8F 90 91 92 93    .....  .....
94 95 96 97 98 - 99 9A 9B 9C 9D    .....  .....
9E 9F 80 81 82 - 83 84 85 86 87    .....  .....
88 89 8A 8B 8C - 8D 8E 8F 90 91    .....  .....
92 93 94 95 96 - 97 98 99 9A 9B    .....  .....
9C 9D 9E 9F A0 - A1 A2 A3 A4 A5    .....  .....
A6 A7 A8 A9 AA - AB AC AD AE AF    .....  .....
B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 - B5 B6 B7 B8 B9    .....  .....
BA BB BC BD BE - BF A0 A1 A2 A3    .....  .....
A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 - A9 AA AB AC AD    .....  .....
AE AF B0 B1 B2 - B3 B4 B5 B6 B7    .....  .....
B8 B9 BA BB BC - BD BE A1 23 E1    .....  ...#.
```

At this configuration there seems to be an extra bit no. 8 set to 1 and again missing bit no. 6.

Any suggestion on the problem origin?

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded right .hex to your MCU? I mean, maybe you have changed `UCSRC` in older FW versions and then you only think that it is wrong.

Comment: I have checked them all many times

Answer (score 1):

`#define BAUDRATE ((F_CPU)/(UART_BAUD*16UL)-1)`

with *F_CPU = 1'000'000*, *UART_BAUD = 19'200* and rounding downwards gives you:

*1000000 / (19200 * 16) - 1 = 2*

and actual uart speed will be

*1000000 / 16 / (2 + 1) = 20833*

which gives you 8.5% error.

Even enabling 2x mode (`U2X` in `UCSRA`) will not help. It is not possible to correctly setup USART to communicate on this speed, when clocking from 1MHz source.

But, when clocking from the internal RC-oscillator you can select higher output speed of the prescaler (by setting the fuses accordingly, or doing it programmatically).

E.g. you can select 2 MHz main clock frequency and setup the USART to utilize 2x mode:

```
// rounding toward nearest integer, instead of downwards
// divide by 8 (instead of 16) in 2x mode
#define BAUDRATE ((F_CPU + (UART_BAUD*4))/(UART_BAUD*8)-1) // set baud rate value for UBRR

...

void uart_init (void)
{
    // the gcc compiler is able to update UBRRH and UBRRL on its own
    UBRR  = BAUDRATE;                           // set baud rate
    UCSRA = (1 << U2X);                         // enable 2x mode
    UCSRB = (1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXEN);                // enable receiver and transmitter
    UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<UCSZ1);   // 8bit data format
}
...
```

Now, with *F_CPU = 2'000'000*, *BAUDRATE* value will be:

*(2000000 + (4 * 19200)) / (8 * 19200) - 1 = 12*

And actual speed:

*2000000 / 8 / (12 + 1) = 19231*

which gives less than 0.2% error

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to solve the problem
I just added an external crystal and it started working flawlessly.
I didn't expect that much of effect from internal oscillator!!!!

Comment: So, internal RC couldn't handle this baud rate? Maybe frame % error was too big, look at tables in datasheet. :)